# PythonでOpenpyxl 特定のCellに変数のリストを貼り付ける

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Pythonのopenpyxlモジュールを使って以下の動きを実現したいのですが、どうしてもうまくいきません。

「A列に"New"という文字列があれば、そこから1行下、5列左にあるセルに変数に格納されているリストの値を貼り付ける、貼り付けたら一行下のセルにリストの次の値を貼り付ける。」

以下のサンプルが現状書いたコードですが、ここからはどうやって書けば上記の動きを実現できるでしょうか？ご教示いただけますとたすかります。

＜サンプル＞

```
import openpyxl
import win32com.client
import os

#Get Flag items from outlook

object = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
mapi = object.GetNamespace('MAPI')
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Flag = []

for item in inbox.items:
    if item.IsMarkedAsTask:
        Flag.append(item.subject)

#Update Task list excel    

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop")
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('★★★.xlsx')
task_sheet=wb['Task']
task_sheet['A1'] 
New=task_sheet['A1']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「リスト」というのが `Flag[]` だとすると、以下のようになると考えられます。
A列には、何かしらの有効な値が入っていることを前提にしています。

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Desktop")
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('★★★.xlsx')
task_sheet=wb['Task']

fLen = len(Flag)
for i in range(1,(task_sheet.max_row + 1)):
    if task_sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value == "New":
        j = i + 1
        for k in range(0,fLen):
            task_sheet.cell(row=(j + k), column=6).value = Flag[k]
        break
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。先ほど上記のコードを使ってPythonファイルを実行してみましたがFlagのアイテムはエクセルに転記されませんでした。ほかに何か使いで各べきコードがあるのでしょうか？A列には"New"をひとつ入力することで、そこなら一行下へ5列右へ行くための目印にしております。

Comment: `.value`への代入で良いはずですが、もう一つは3つ目のパラメータとして`value=Flag[k]` を指定する方法でしょうか。あとは、`Flag[k]` 自身を明示的に `string`としてencodingも含めて指定しておくくらいでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにあとはエクセルに実際に値が貼り付けられるだけな気がします。str(Flag[k])にし、コードの一番上に# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-にしたのですが、あっていますか？間違っている場合教えていただけると助かります。上記2点以外に設定する必要がある場合はそちらもご教示いただけると大変たすかります。

Comment: python.fileの実行方法ですが、idleでpythonファイルをOpen、その後F5を押して実行しているのですが合っていますか？ネットでファイル拡張子の関連付という記事を読んだのですがこちらは関係ありますか？プログラミング初心者なもので矢継ぎ早に質問してしまい申し訳ありません。一応ご迷惑おかけしないように自力でいろいろ調べてはいるのですが、どうしてもまだモヤモヤしていてうまくこれだという答えにたどり着けません。。。

Comment: encodingはpython3系ならそれで良いと思われます。実行方法も大丈夫です。　拡張子関連付けは、IDEとかインタプリタでスクリプトを読み込んで実行するのではなく、`.py`のファイルをファイル名を打つだけで`.bat`ファイルのように実行させるためのものです。　開発中の実行確認は、随所にprint()でその時々の変数の値がどうなっているかを表示させて行うのが良いでしょう。書く前の値や、書いた後の読み返した値をprint()することも方法のひとつです。　それからワークブックのsave()やclose()もきちんと行っていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。Print()にて変数の値をチェックし、欲しい情報が格納されていることと、.セルに貼り付けたいセルの場所も適切になっていることは確認しました。となるとワークブックのSave()やClos()が原因ですかね。ただ該当のエクセルを開きっぱなしにし、Pythonファイルを実行してその開きっぱなしのエクセルを再度見てもセルに変数の値は代入されません。。。

Comment: エクセルでワークシートを開きっぱなしにしたものと、Pythonで同じワークシートを処理したものは、別々のものです。　ネットワークの共有フォルダにある１つのファイルを別々の人が別々のPCから同時に更新するイメージに近いです。　同じエクセルで処理するなら、エクセルの排他チェックが働いて、後から開いた人は読み取りモードになったりしますが、エクセルとPython+openpyxlでは、それは機能しないかもしれません。　Pythonで処理した後、エクセルはいったん終了させてから開き直してみてください。